# Get Predicates with Prefix from an RDF

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, jena

When extracting subject, property, and object from a **RDF** file, I want to replace the IRI of the predicate with the keyword it corresponds to. For example, A general **SPARQL** query returns these results:

```
| <http://extbi.dk/resource/727> | <http://extbi.dk/p/population> | "21,749"                                             
| <http://extbi.dk/resource/727> | <http://extbi.dk/p/region> | "Central"                                                
| <http://extbi.dk/resource/727> | <http://extbi.dk/p/id>   | "727"
```

What I want to do is: If the prefix keyword for *http://extbi.dk/p/* is **schema**, then my desired result is:

```
| <http://extbi.dk/resource/727> | <schema:population> | "21,749"                                             
| <http://extbi.dk/resource/727> | <schema:region> | "Central"                                                
| <http://extbi.dk/resource/727> | <schema:id>   | "727"
```

I am using Apache Jena.

Comment: What prevents you from replacing the URIs in the Java code? If not `BIND(replace(str(?s), "http://extbi.dk/p/", "schema:") as ?newS)` is the function you need in SPARQL

Comment: @AKSW The problem is: I don't know the URI or the prefix corresponds to it in advance. Also, there could be multiple URI and multiple prefixes. Is there any way to do it by SPARQL query? I can do it with regular expression but SPARQL is preffered.

Comment: But the prefixes must exists in advance, how else would you do it? Prefixes are just syntactic sugar. Without a prefix mapping, how should SPARQL do it? Somewhere the mapping `prefix -> namespace` must exist. Either in the triple store, or in your mind. If not, you could always try to get the part that comes after `#` or `/` although this might not be correct and you still need some prefix, e.g. `ns1, ns2, ..., `. If you're loading an RDF dataset via Jena, existing prefix mappings of the dataset are accessible as shown in the answer below. But not via SPARQL query.

Comment: It would also be interesting to see how you load the data, run the query, and show the result of the query - this would allow to suggest the most useful way.

Answer (score 0):

Prefixes are handled in Jena using `PrefixMapping` objects.

This example should return QName or null if it doesnt exists:

```
Node n;
PrefixMapping prefixes = new PrefixMapping.Factory.create();
qnameFor(n.getURI());
```

`shortForm(String URI)` can also be used to simplify an URI based on the "original" URI resource.

Here is the link to the Javadoc : [Link](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/shared/PrefixMapping.html).

Comment: I don't follow. Would you please explain your answer? I can't find the method qNameOrURI also.